# Angular getElementById() returns null in switch statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single page app in which 'pages' are switching with ng-switch. On second page I have a modal and I'm opening it using such function:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
vm.openModal = function(src) {
   modal.style.display = 'block';
   modalImg.src = src;
};
modal.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
};
```

And my html:

```
<div ng-switch="vm.step.name">
  <div ng-switch-when="prepare">
      Some content of first page
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="action">
      Some content of second page
      <button ng-click="vm.openModal('bootHP.jpg')">Open modal</button>
      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal-instruction absolute block">
        <img class="modal-content-guide centered" id="img01">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm getting var modal = null, so for some reason It doesn't see id='myModal' in switch. Could someone please help me clarify why it behaves in this way and how can I try to solve this?

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Try angular.element($document).find('myModal'); you'll need to inject $document ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `document.getElementById` from the controller body (i.e. it is executed when the controller is constructed) the DOM inside the `ng-switch` most likely doesn't exist yet.

To be certain it exists, you could postpone getting it only when `openModal()` is executed.

```
vm.openModal = function(src) {
    var modal = angular.element('#myModal');
    modal.css('display', 'block');
    modalImg.src = src;
};
```

Considering the click event, be sure to unregister the event when your controller is destroyed.